# Evaluating space curves

Tags: classical-mechanics

What does it mean to evaluate a function on a space curve?

Eg for the following question

Consider the space curve deﬁned by the following position vector: 
$$r(t) = \cos t \ i + \sin t \ j + t \ k$$
and the scalar valued function: 
$$V (x, y, z ) = (1/2)*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) $$
Evaluate the function on the space curve, and then compute its derivative with respect to t.

I have no problem in computing the answer as $(1+t^2)/2$, then the derivative as t, however I don't understand the theory behind this.

Comment: You're doing composition of functions. Perhaps what is interesting to discover/remember is the chain rule, which will tell you that $$\frac d{dt} V(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = \nabla V(x(t),y(t),z(t))\cdot (x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))\,.$$

Comment: see a picture [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%28cos+t+%2C+sin+t+%2Ct%2F5%29%2C%7Bt%2C-8%2C8%7D ]

Answer (score 0):

You have a composition of $r:{\Bbb{R}}\to{\Bbb{R}}^3$ with $V:{\Bbb{R}}^3\to{\Bbb{R}}$, i.e.
you have a new function
$$V\circ r:{\Bbb{R}}\to {\Bbb{R}},$$
which represents the effect of measuring $V$ along an helice's curve.

Comment: the derivative satisfy $(V\circ r)'={\rm grad V}\bullet r'$ tells you how $V$ varies in the tangent direction $r'$.